# How can I access properties (such as variables or objects) of an anonymous self-invoking function with a console?

Tags: javascript, console

I have a website with the following code:

```
(function() {
    var x = "Welcome!";
    var o = {"date": Date.now(), "elapsed": null};
})();
```

Is it possible to access the variables `x` and `o` (such as logging their value) from a browser console? If so, how?

Comment: All javascript can be exposed to the console. You can edit the source code in developer tools and add console.logs or add debugger/breakpoints.

Comment: Not possible. That's (usually) the whole point of using an IIFE. You can always just put a breakpoint there and step through the code, though.